# Laravel using façades in a job

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up a Job that uses the `Storage` facade. Unfortunately this is not working and is throwing an Exception.

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not
>   allowed

```
class MoveMusicToRemoteStorage extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, DispatchesJobs;

    private $audio;

    public function __construct(AudioFile $audio)
    {
        $this->audio = $audio;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/audio/' . $this->audio->file()->getFilename(), file_get_contents($this->audio->getPath()));
    }

}
```

How can I use a Facade within the job?

**EDIT**

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512381/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-uploadedfile-is-not-all) but I do not own the File class so I cannot make it Serializable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512381/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-uploadedfile-is-not-all)

Comment: @MahmoudTantawy no this is not the same as my question

Comment: It is, because that’s the issue. Read the exception message.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing a `File` object to the job constructor and the file cannot be serialized. It has nothing to do with the façade. You can use the façade as you are, but to get around the problem, you need to pass a reference to the file you want (like its file name/path) and then retrieve the file via the `File` façade within your `handle()` method:

```
class MoveMusicToRemoteStorage extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, DispatchesJobs;

    private $audio_file_path;

    public function __construct($audio_file_path)
    {
        $this->audio_file_path = $audio_file_path;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $audio_file = Storage::get($this->audio_file_path);

        Storage::disk('s3')->put('/audio/' . $audio_file->file()->getFilename(), file_get_contents($audio_file->getPath()));
    }    
}
```

If you are doing this with a file upload, you will probably want to not use a job. File uploads are stored in the temporary directory and the file could disappear before you have a chance to move it to S3 if the job were ever to be queued.

Comment: As exception message states: the issue is `File` cannot be serialized, nothing to do with façades.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. I realize it has nothing to do with facades. I mention that in my answer. The OP's title, however make's it look like the questions is all about façades.

Comment: Yeah, this was aimed at the OP, not you. Was just reiterating what you said :)

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, I was getting confused because `AudioFile` does not extend `File` it's a custom class - but I see that I use `File` when accessing the `$this->audio->file()` method. I've implemented Serializable on the `AudioFile` class and all it working. Thanks