# Unite Test: Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I'm trying to write white test to test my API with file uploads.

I'm following the [docs about this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client)  using basic client request, not crawler.

The unit test is:

```
class RecordsControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

private $client;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->client = self::createClient();
    $this->client->insulate();
}

public function testApiPostUpload($params){
    $fileToUpload = realpath(__DIR__.'/../../resources/mpthreetest.mp3');
    $file = new UploadedFile(
        $fileToUpload,
        'mpthreetest.mp3',
        MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance()->guess($fileToUpload),
        filesize($fileToUpload)
    );
    $this->client->request('POST', '/records/'.$params['createdRecordId'].'/upload', array(), array('file' => $file) );

    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
}
```

When I execute the test I receive an error:

```
Exception: Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

/path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:165
/path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:348
/path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:143
/path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:313
/path/to/project/src/Bundle/Tests/Functional/Controller/RecordsControllerTest.php:182
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512381/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-uploadedfile-is-not-all) for about the same error, but in this case the request is not sent to the controller and the problem is not the entity and implementing serialization.

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Anyone who managed to make unit test for uploading file in symfony 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to NOT insulate the requests passing false as argument to the insulate method so try this:

```
$this->client->insulate(false);
```

instead of this:

```
$this->client->insulate();
```

Hope this help

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks !

Comment: I have the same problem, but for me, `insulate(false)` does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by setting the `changeHistory` parameter to false (7th and last parameter in the request method signature):

```
$crawler = $client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values, $files, [], null, false);
```

This will prevent the serialize on following lines :

```
if ($this->followRedirects && $this->redirect) {
        $this->redirects[serialize($this->history->current())] = true;
        return $this->crawler = $this->followRedirect();
}
```