# Serialization of UploadedFile is not allowed

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, hwioauthbundle, vichuploaderbundle

I'm trying to upload a file via [vichuploader bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) on my Users entity.
Using [hwioauthbundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) that implements UserInterface, and i think the errors comes from that bundle...
So  every time i try to uplod a file i got this exception :

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile'
>   is not allowed

I already tried  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512381/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-uploadedfile-is-not-all) but also same exception.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser;


/**
 * Users 
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 *
 */
class Users extends  OAuthUser 
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="civility", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $civility;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $avatar;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qualification", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $qualification;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hiring_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hiringDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="linkedin_profil", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $linkedinProfil;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="web_site", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $webSite;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_last_cnx", type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateLastCnx;


    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Files",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $cv;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $google_id;
```

Files.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Files
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files 
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

        /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    protected $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $imageName;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }





    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if ($image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }


}
```

My form Userstype:

```
use AppBundle\Form\FilesType;


->add('cv',FilesType::class)
```

My form Filestype:

```
 -> add('imageFile',

 VichFileType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, 
            'download_link' => true,
            'label' => false, 

        ]);
```

Comment: your user entity seems to be missing ` @Vich\Uploadable` annotation  are you sure you followed the required steps according to the official docs ?  https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.mdalso if you post the complete code for your user entity we might be able to capture the error

Comment: thank you for replaying,Take i look i updated the post i used to work with vich, and it works fine before setting tha authentification with hwioauthbundle...

Comment: I saw you put `sleep` method and removed it form the question. Try implementing Serializable on your `Files` entity and get that sleep method back with a small modification : you should not return the file field as probably that what causing the problem

Comment: i alredy tried with Serializable : public function serialize()
    { return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
$this->cv));} Can you come chat room plz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are serializing `ImageFile` entity within this code that's why you are getting the error , try removing that and add `updatedAt` field so that doctrine can track changes on the entity:

```
/**
 * Files
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Files implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

        /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    protected $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }





    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if ($image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

  /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->imageName,

        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,

        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $updatedAt
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

for Symfony5

```
Class User implement UserInterface

public function __serialize(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'email' => $this->email,
            //......
        ];
    }

public function __unserialize(array $serialized): User
{
    $this->id = $serialized['id'];
    $this->email = $serialized['email'];
    // .....
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, one of your Users's relation has an UploadedFile property, which is essentially a File aka a filestream which aren't allowed to be serialized. Therefore you need to specify what you want to serialized:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/entity_provider.html

Basically you only neeed to serialized id, username and password (three is an example code on the above page)